# RxJava 2 Observable that onComplete resubmits itself

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

I'm new with RxJava. I'm trying to create an observable that when it completes it will start all over again until I call dispose, but I'm facing an OutofMemory error after a while, below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do

```
  public void start() throws RuntimeException {
        log.info("\t * Starting {} Managed Service...", getClass().getSimpleName());

        try {

            executeObserve();

            log.info("\t * Starting {} Managed Service...OK!", getClass().getSimpleName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Managed Service {} FAILED! Reason is {} ", getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

**start** is invoked at the initialization phase once, the executeObserve is as follows (in a simplified form..). Notice that on the onComplete I "resubmit" executeObserve

```
public void executeObserve() throws RuntimeException {

        Observable<Book> booksObserve
                = manager.getAsObservable();

        booksObserve
                 .map(Book::getAllOrders)
                 .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
                 .toList()
                 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                 .subscribe(collectedISBN ->  
                      Observable.fromIterable(collectedISBN)
                       .buffer(10)
                       // ...some more steps here...
                       .toList()
                       .toObservable()
                       // resubmit
                      .doOnComplete(this::executeObserve)
                      .subscribe(validISBN -> {
                             // do something with the valid ones
                      })
             )
        );
    }
```

My guess is that this is not the way to go if I want to resubmit my tasks but it was not possible to find any documentation.

the booksObserve is implemented as follows

```
public Observable<Book> getAsObservable() {
    return Observable.create(e -> {
        try (CloseableResultSet<Book> rs = (CloseableResultSet<Book>) datasource.retrieveAll())) {
            for (Book r : rs) {
                e.onNext(r);
            }
            e.onComplete();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            e.onError(ex);
        }
    });
}
```

What is the correct way to constantly resubmit an operation until we call dispose or equivalent? I'm using RxJava 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created an endless recursion, the loop will create more and more resources and sometime it will blow with OutOfMemory/Stack overflow exception.

In order to repeat the `Observable` work you should use `repeat()` operator, it will resubscribes to the `Observable` when it receives `onComplete()`.

Besides that, some general comments on your code:

- why are you nesting the second `Observable` inside the subscriber? you are breaking the chain, you can just continue the chain instead of creating new `Observable` at the Subscriber.
- Moreover, it's seems (assuming O`bservable.fromIterable(collectedBets)` using the `collectedISBN` that gets with the `onNext()` o.w. from where does it comes?) you're collecting all items to a list, and then flatting it again using from iterable, so it's seems you can just continue on the stream , something like that:

  ```
  booksObserve
     .map(Book::getAllOrders)
     .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
     .buffer(10)
     // ...some more steps here...
     .toList()
     .toObservable()
     // resubmit
     .doOnComplete(this::executeObserve)
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .subscribe(validISBN -> {
           // do something with the valid ones
      });
  ```
- Anyhow, with the nested `Observable`, the `repeat()` operator will just repeat the nested one, and not the entire stream (which is what you want) as it is not connected to it.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your answer, +1 for the repeat. I have one question though, the datasource within the `booksObserve` will it be called with the use of the repeat? Or it will be the same initial set of results? I corrected the typo with the collectedISBN

Comment: it will be called again, the repeat() operator will **subscribes** again to your Observable meaning that your subscribe logic - the datasource.retrieveAll() etc. **will** be called again

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to my question the `repeat` as @yosriz suggested is the proper way to go, the following simple snippet demonstrates that the observable source will be called on each repeat

```
Observable<Integer> recursiveObservable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
            System.out.println("Calling to emit data");
            Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0).forEach(emitter::onNext);
            emitter.onComplete();
        });
        recursiveObservable
                .buffer(2)
                .repeat()
                .subscribe(integers -> {
                    System.out.println(integers);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                });
```